Laravel Herd parked serving sites at http://directory-name>.test not working
I'm completely new to PHP, Laravel and Herd world. As a matter of fact this is my first bite in trying out things using Laravel chirper project.
Here's overview of my setup in Windows 10.
I started by installing PHP v8.2.17 and composer but somehow I went further to install Laravel Herd as npm wouldn't work in project directory for some reasons I really can't tell, cause node and npm has been working fine before now.
So I uninstalled the php-8.2.17 for the cli to properly point to PHP in herd.
Everything seems to setup correctly but the site (chirper.test) would not open, I'm getting This site can't be reached with Nginx and PHP-8.2 services running.
I have run herd park and herd link at c:\Users\user\Herd> according to the herd serving site documentations but the issue remains the same and I don't know what am not doing right.
Any support would be appreciated 

What does "wouldn't work" mean? Is this a PHP problem, a Laravel problem a nginx problem, or a Composer problem?

@NicoHaase It's a Laravel Herd problem which was not loading parked sites.

Solved! I went to the Herd general settings page and I found the HerdHelper Port 5000 status to be red  all I did was just to change the port and restarted all services and boom! It work.
